# facebook API limitation bypass by changing ip or using proxy with php

Tags: php, facebook, proxy

I read that facbook api limiting is 600 calls per 600 seconds, per token & per IP.
First of all: clients oder servers ip? Since im using php im not sure.
What if I change ip or use a Proxy?
Can anyone teach me how set up a proxy in php and change it while running?
I tried to wait 600 secs with sleep(600) after 558 calls. But it doesnt work. Also doesent work to sleep(1) after each api call.
Any other ideas to bypass the limiting?

Comment: How about you first describe _why_ you (think you) need to make so many API calls that you run into the limits …?

Comment: Also, minor corrections, there are also CPU usage limits which are much harder to prodict, and IP address is only considered for calls without an access token as far as i know

Answer (score 0):

Of course there's a way to do it. You can do this by using [Tor proxy](https://www.torproject.org/).

I tried it on some other social network where the API call limit was 500 calls/hour. I was able to solve this problem by telling the Tor to change the IP address after every 2 minutes. And yeah, I used **JAVA** to make API calls to the network, but am pretty sure you can do the same in case of Facebook (unless FB is smart enough to block the API calls from Tor) and using PHP.

Try to learn more about Tor proxy and how to change your IP address after every certain period of time. The research part will surely take some time, but you'll learn quite a lot from this task.

Answer (score 0):

Steps for creating tor proxy.

1. Install the software tor, not the tor browser. On debian based systems it is `apt-get install tor`.
2. Edit /etc/tor/torrc  by uncommenting the line

   SocksPort 9050

   ControlPort 9051

   CookieAuthentication 1

   HashedControlPassword 16:E600ADC1B52C80BB6022A0E999A7734571A451EB6AE50FED489B72E3DF
3. Install polipo
4. Edit /etc/polipo/config

   allowedClients = 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.0/24 # Expose your network (modify accordingly)

   socksParentProxy = "localhost:9051"

   socksProxyType = socks5

   proxyAddress = "0.0.0.0"    # IPv4 only
5. Restart both tor and polipo. Configure application to route through proxy.

Reference https://www.marcus-povey.co.uk/2016/03/24/using-tor-as-a-http-proxy/